# Ubuntu Desktop: Can't open Terminal or File Manager

Tags: server, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I installed Ubuntu Desktop Lite v18 on my Dell PowerEdge T30 server. Now I can't open the Terminal or File Manager app. But I can launch Chrome fine.

When I click on the Terminal icon in the taskbar, I see a tab in the menu on the top of the screen said Terminal with a spinning circle. After few seconds, the tab in the menu got disappeared.

How should I fix this?

Comment: You need to give more details, what exactly is happening? You double click a folder and nothing happens? You open Terminal from the menu but it does not start? Did you try the shortcut Ctrl + Alt + T?

Comment: @VoltBit Updated description, see above, please.

Comment: You can switch to another tty to see if you get any errors. Use this: Ctrl + Alt + F2. You will have a command prompt, there try to run the terminal like this: gnome-terminal or /usr/bin/gnome-terminal. See if you get any errors. To go back to the UI use Ctrl + Alt + F7.

Comment: Sorry, the Lite Ubuntu is using LXDE it seems, so it does not have gnome terminal I guess. Try to open the terminal with **lxterminal** after switching to tty2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2).